# I want my sidenav to push the content from the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

OK so I have a strange request. I have a normal content page and a sidebar that goes from left to right . At the moment , when i click on the icon , the navbar goes to the left and pushes the content but it only makes it resize (the content of the main page) . I need the content to move with the navbar but it needs to be removed . Like dissapering behind the page . I have no idea if that makes sence to you guys. 
[image]

Maybe this image will help somehow so you could understand .

```
<body>
<div class="pop opened">
    <nav class="pop-nav">
        <div class="pop-links">
            <li><a href="javascript:;">What we do</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="pop-social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:;"><span><i class="s s-facebook footer-soc"></i></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;"><span><i class="s s-twitter footer-soc"></i></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;"><span><i class="s s-youtube footer-soc"></i></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <!--Icon missing instead of img--><img src="./images/logo_desktop.png" alt="HCI Logo" class="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <nav class="header-nav">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;">What we do</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>
                    </nav>
                    <span><i class="s s-hamburger hamburger"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <section class="hero" style="background-image: url(./images/hero.png)">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row row-big">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-small">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn">Sign up now<span><i class="s s-arrow"></i></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is the important part with the navigation. THe rest is just page content.

```
.main {
  transition: margin-right .5s;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pop {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $dark-blue;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;

  .pop-nav {
    padding: 46px 0 0 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid $grey-blue;
    margin: 79px 0 0;
    @include breakpoint(phone) {
        padding: 33px 0 0 35px;
    }
  }
}

.pop-links {
  padding-bottom: 65px;

  li {

    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 40px;

    &:last-child {
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }

  a {
    color: $white;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me.

```
$('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')){
            $(window).resize(function(){
                if ($(window).width() <= 640){
                    $('.pop').css({'width' : '255px'});
                    $('.main').css({'margin-right' : '255px' , "padding-right" : "255px"});
                }
                else{
                    $('.pop').css({'width' : '550px'});
                    $('.main').css({'margin-right' : '550px'});
                }
            }).resize();
        }
        else {
            $('.pop').css({'width' : '0'});
            $('.main').css({'margin-right' : '0'});
        }
    })
```

Comment: Take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: Make two divs that are side by side. Left one has width 0vw, right one has width 100vw and make the left one expand while the right one contracts with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so hard to do(only to figure out),

When you have javascript to open your sidenav you probably have a code that sets the display on block or width to a certain amount onclick, in that same funtion add all the elements to push aside in var's and give them margin-left the same amount as the width of the sidenav. that will make it look like the sidenav pushing content away

EDIT:

what i did was:

css:

```
#main {
transition: margin-left .5s;
}
.sidenav {
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

javascript:

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

just edit this to what you need, so change #main with all the content you want to push and .sidenav with your sidenav and play around with the left, width and transition

Comment: oh an my nav is pushing the content , but the content is just getting smaller in size , i need it to dissapear from the page ... something like overflow

Comment: in your case with the nav from right to left use marginleft = "-250px";

Comment: This wasn't exactly what i needed but it gave me a clue ! Thanks ! Keep up the good work ! :)